# How to force the whole app re-render when change app language with i18n?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

My app target both Arabic and English language and i am trying to change the whole app language and force the whole app to update including FormattedProvider that helps me include both Arabic and English numbers in my app, i use its tags as a wrapper on my main App.js app component, as shown here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 
'react-native';
import * as Expo from 'expo';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { FormattedProvider } from 'react-native-globalize';
import InnerApp from './src/App';
import i18n from './src/i18n';    

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
            'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
            'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
            'Ionicons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
            'FontAwesome': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf'),
            'Foundation': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Foundation.ttf'),
            'SimpleLineIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf'),
            'EvilIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/EvilIcons.ttf'),
            'MaterialIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf'),
            'FontAwesome5_Regular': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf')
       });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FormattedProvider locale={this.props.language}>
                <InnerApp />
            </FormattedProvider>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    },
    paragraph: {
        margin: 24,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#34495e',
    },
});
```

and i want the whole app language changes when user choose another language, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i integrated it in a separate file import { Localization } from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import ar from './ar.json';
import en from './en.json';

console.log(Localization.locale);

i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { ar, en };
// i18n.locale = Localization.locale;
console.log(i18n.locale);

export default i18n;

Comment: @skyboyer what do you mean with I18NextProvider ?

Comment: What i mean with i18n is "I18n-js" javascript library

Comment: And i implemented it as described in docs but i can't figure out how to force update app state when user change app language

Answer (score 0):

Try something around this:

```
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state = {
               language: "en"
            }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if (this.props.language != nextProps.language)
       this.setState({language: nextProps.language})
}

render() {
    return (
        <FormattedProvider locale={this.state.language}>
            <InnerApp />
        </FormattedProvider>
    )
}
}
```

Basically just try to read the language from state so the tree is re rendered when it is changed.

Comment: I gave it a try but nothing gona change... the language stay the same

Comment: My life cycle component is something like componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (this.props.language != nextProps.language)
      i18n.locale=nextProps.language;
      this.setState({language: nextProps.language});
  }